# Converting date format produce by excel to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

Asking for any ideas to convert this kind of date in SQL from **May-15-2020 18:03** to '**yyyyMMddHHmiss**' or '**yyyyMMdd**'.

I am trying this query

```
 select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('May-15-2020 16:03', 'MM-dd-yyyy
 HH:mi'), 'yyyyMMdd') from dual
```

but it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the right right function [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), and use a format that matches your date rather than something **scraped** from a previous answer/blog.

[Reference manuals of date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) are very useful for solving these basic problems.